# how to dynamically instantiate a C# class from assembly, other then running one

Tags: c#, .net

I have an assembly (which is other then my running assembly) named "Gcim.Management.Module.dll", from which I need to instantiate a specific class:

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Projects\Gcim.Management\Gcim.Management.Module\bin\Debug\Gcim.Management.Module.dll");
```

The class, in which I'm, interested, has a name of "DataSources".
I'm trying to iterate over this assembly and match what I'm looking for by name:

```
var types = myAssembly.ManifestModule.GetTypes();

foreach (var item in types)
{
    if(item.Name == "DataSources")
    {
        Type myType = Type.GetType(item.FullName);

        object targetObject = ObjectSpace.CreateObject(myType);
    }
}
```

The `"ObjectSpace.CreateObject"` comes from a third-party library, and for it to work, it needs a valid `myType`.
I am getting a match as I iterate, but `myType` remains null after `Type myType = Type.GetType(item.FullName);`

What is the proper way to get the assembly type, so I could instantiate an object of that type?

Comment: `Type myType = item;`

Comment: `item` is already a type.  You don't need to do anything.

Comment: isn't `GetTypes` returning a sequence of `Type`-instances? why doing another `Type.GetType`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using LoadFile.  If the dll was built with symbols you can simply add the dll to your project like any library.  From Project menu : Add Reference : Browse to location of dll (usually in the project bin folder).  The add to top of module a using statement add the library.

Comment: @jdweng maybe the OP is doing dynamic plugins - good catch though!

Comment: The title says dynamic, but WHY?

Comment: @jdweng I assume OP is loading assembly at run time like a plugin so he may not have luxury of compilation. Sort of Di

Comment: Why are you loading the assembly dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `item.Name=="DataSources"` returns `true`, then item is the type you want...don't need to call Type.GetType to get it.

However, to answer your question, Type.GetType( string name ) will only return types by full name in the current assembly or the "core" assembly (mscorlib). You can use the assembly qualified name instead...

```
Type.GetType( item.AssemblyQualifiedName )
```

It will then find the type.

Comment: I think Type.GetType needs an assembly qualified name in all cases with TWO exceptions - mscorlib and currently executing assembly